# Drag UILable in only UIImageview frame Using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

**UILable** Drag In **UIView** frame Not In **UIImageView** frame I am using following code for drag lable using **UIPanGestureRecognizer**

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture1:)];
    [panGesture setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [self.imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x,self.imageView.frame.origin.y ,self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height)];
    [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    panGesture.delegate=self;
    [title addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
    panGesture = nil;
```

And my action method

```
-(void)handlePanGesture1:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

  CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.imageView];
  if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 

{

     firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
     firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
}

 translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

    [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `panGesture = nil;` when adding to your label? this will make the pan gesture pointer to get `nil` this is an invalid approach. (I'm guessing you are thinking non-ARC) Plus, what was the question again?

Comment: i am new in ios but try without panGesture = nil; but issue same my lable drag in uiview not only uiimageview

Comment: That's because you should somehow constraint the movement beyond `UIImageView`. e.g. You could Max or Min x,y positions after calculation before setting your view's position to let label roam into your desired view only.

Comment: i try this but not geting proper       if((min_X >= self.imageView.frame.origin.x && max_X <=  self.imageView.frame.origin.x +  self.imageView.frame.size.width) && (min_Y >=  self.imageView.frame.origin.y && max_Y <=  self.imageView.frame.origin.y +  self.imageView.frame.size.height))
        {
            title.center = newCenter;
        }

Comment: That's too complicated a solution. Let me get back at you in a more proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, You should Limit your x,y using something like this:

```
    CGFloat maxPossibleX = CGRectGetMaxX(self.imageView.frame) - (CGRectGetWidth(sender.view.bounds)/2.0f);
    CGFloat maxPossibleY = CGRectGetMaxY(self.imageView.frame) - (CGRectGetHeight(sender.view.bounds) /2.0f);

    CGFloat minPossibleX = CGRectGetMinX(self.imageView.frame) + CGRectGetMidX(sender.view.bounds);
    CGFloat minPossibleY = CGRectGetMinY(self.imageView.frame) + CGRectGetMidY(sender.view.bounds);


    CGFloat actualX = translatedPoint.x;
    actualX= MAX(minPossibleX, actualX);
    actualX = MIN(maxPossibleX, actualX);

    CGFloat actualY = translatedPoint.y;
    actualY= MAX(minPossibleY, actualY);
    actualY = MIN(maxPossibleY, actualY);

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(actualX, actualY);
```

I'm assuming your label is not a subview of your imageView here. If your label is subview of imageView:

```
    CGFloat maxPossibleX = CGRectGetMaxX(self.imageView.bounds) - (CGRectGetWidth(sender.view.bounds)/2.0f);
    CGFloat maxPossibleY = CGRectGetMaxY(self.imageView.bounds) - (CGRectGetHeight(sender.view.bounds) /2.0f);

    CGFloat minPossibleX = CGRectGetMidX(sender.view.bounds);
    CGFloat minPossibleY = CGRectGetMidY(sender.view.bounds);


    CGFloat actualX = translatedPoint.x;
    actualX= MAX(minPossibleX, actualX);
    actualX = MIN(maxPossibleX, actualX);

    CGFloat actualY = translatedPoint.y;
    actualY= MAX(minPossibleY, actualY);
    actualY = MIN(maxPossibleY, actualY);

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(actualX, actualY);
```

Edit: I have successfully tested this method in a test project:

```
-(void)handlePanGesture1:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.imageView];
    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)

    {

        firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
        firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

    CGFloat maxPossibleX = CGRectGetMaxX(self.imageView.bounds) - (CGRectGetWidth(sender.view.bounds)/2.0f);
    CGFloat maxPossibleY = CGRectGetMaxY(self.imageView.bounds) - (CGRectGetHeight(sender.view.bounds) /2.0f);

    CGFloat minPossibleX = CGRectGetMidX(sender.view.bounds);
    CGFloat minPossibleY = CGRectGetMidY(sender.view.bounds);


    CGFloat actualX = translatedPoint.x;
    actualX= MAX(minPossibleX, actualX);
    actualX = MIN(maxPossibleX, actualX);

    CGFloat actualY = translatedPoint.y;
    actualY= MAX(minPossibleY, actualY);
    actualY = MIN(maxPossibleY, actualY);

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(actualX, actualY);
    [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];
}
```

Comment: i am using lable as subview on imageview and i try this code my lable drag in x=0 in uiview (corner) fix and not moved on other positions

Comment: I have created a test project and tested my code in action. it works flawlessly when I remove the line  `[self.imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x,self.imageView.frame.origin.y ,self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height)];` I'm not sure why you are setting bounds for image view. Use the second code example and lose that line, it should get fixed.

Comment: Glad to hear, just as a side note: [How to Accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: when i try to drag lable why it started from x=0 on UIImageView

Comment: I'm not facing such a problem in my experience. It could be something that is manipulating `firstX`, `firstY`. Or they might get zeroed somewhere.